# DataSet.Locate с преобразованием числового поля в стринговое не работает

Tags: delphi, firebird

В БД *firebird* поле «*NUMERAL_DSTU*» integer, в нем числа например «*302095*».
В *dataset*, сделал вычисляемое поля типа *string*, и присвоил ему:

```
ibdsDSTU.FieldByName('CALC_NUMBER_STRING').AsString := ibdsDSTU.FieldByName('NUMERAL_DSTU').AsString;
```

Делаю *locate*

```
DM.ibdsDSTU.Locate('CALC_NUMBER_STRING', '3020', [loPartialKey]);
```

**Всеравно не позицонируется**. Все получается только при вводе полного значения, т.е. «302095»
У других пишут выходит.

Где ошибка?
Заранее спасибо за ответ

P.S.
вообще пишут, что должно работать, например https://delphi.fandom.com/wiki/TLocateOptions_Type

Comment: Какой тип DataSet'а используется? Возможно стоит заглянуть в его исходники, метод Locate мог быть переопределен.

Comment: в *dataset* использовался *string*, но дело было не в том, а нужно было в самом запросе делать вычисляемое поле, а не в *dataset*